# slim framework withHeader json it does not work

Tags: php, json, header, frameworks, slim

Hello everyone, I'm using slim framework for JSON API all responses work but on headers show text / html, the documentation mentions the function **whitHeader**:

```
    $app = new \Slim\App;
    $app->get('/new/', function (Request $request, Response $response){

        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(['message'=>'ok']));

        $response_h = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return json_decode($response_h);
    });
$app->run();
```

When using **$response_h-> getHeaders ();** show json header(work) but when running takes another header, I tracked where it replaces the header and is in **slim / slim / container.php** exactly in current function **registerDefaultServices** i replace:

```
Headers $ headers = new (['Content-Type' => 'text / html; charset = UTF-8']);
```

to

```
Headers $ headers = new (['Content-Type' => 'application / json; charset = utf-8']);
```

but it is not the best way, how change the headers?

and try using:

```
$ app-> response () -> header ();
$ app-> response () -> setHeader ();
```

In all the return is that the response function () does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [official documentation for Slim Framework v2](http://docs.slimframework.com/response/headers/):

> The HTTP response returned to the HTTP client will have a header. The HTTP header is a list of keys and values that provide metadata about the HTTP response. You can use the Slim application’s response object to set the HTTP response’s header. The response object has a public property `headers` that is an instance of `\Slim\Helper\Set;` this provides a simple, standardized interface to manipulate the HTTP response headers.

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

> You may also fetch headers from the response object's `headers` property, too:

```
<?php
$contentType = $app->response->headers->get('Content-Type');
```

> If a header with the given name does not exist, `null` is returned. You may specify header names with upper, lower, or mixed case with dashes or underscores. Use the naming convention with which you are most comfortable.

Using [official documentation for Slim Framework v3](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#the-response-body):

> An HTTP response typically has a body. Slim provides a PSR 7 Response object with which you can inspect and manipulate the eventual HTTP response’s body.
>
> Just like the PSR 7 Request object, the PSR 7 Response object implements the body as an instance of `\Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface`. You can get the HTTP response body `StreamInterface` instance with the PSR 7 Response object’s `getBody()` method. The `getBody()` method is preferable if the outgoing HTTP response length is unknown or too large for available memory.

Your code should looks like this:

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/new/', function(Request $requst, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(['YOUR_ARRAY']));
    $newResponse = $response->withHeader(
        'Content-type',
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    );

    return $newResponse;
});
```

Tested on my environment with Postman. Content-type were changed.

Comment: Yeah!! thanks Davide thanks to you i found my mistake, on my return i use **return json_encode($newResponse)**, without json_encode works perfectly!